# variable 'opts' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, getopts

the code below runs fine unless I use an unsupported option which prompts the *"UnboundLocalError: local variable 'opts' referenced before assignment"* error. Here is the code. The code worked fine and displayed the exception before using for o,a in opts

```
import socket
import sys
import getopt
import threading
import subprocess

#define some global variables

listen              =False
command             =False
upload              =False
execute             =""
target              =""
upload_destination  =""
port                = 0

def usage():
    print("\nnetcat_replacement tool")
    print()
    print("Usage: netcat_replacement.py -t target_host -p port\n")
    print ("""-l --listen               - listen on [host]:[port] for
                            incoming connections""")
    print("""-e --execute=file_to_run  - execute the given file upon
                            receiving a connection""")
    print("""-c --command              - initialize a command shell""")
    print("""-u --upload=destination   - upon receiving connection upload a
                            file and write to [destination]""")
    print("\n\n")
    print("Examples: ")
    print("netcat_replacement.py -t 192.168.0.1 -p 5555 -l -c")
    print("netcat_replacement.py -t 192.168.0.1 -p 5555 -l -u=c:\\target.exe")
    print('netcat_replacement.py -t 192.168.0.1 -p 5555 -l -e=\"cat /etc/passwd"')
    print("echo 'ABSDEFGHI' | ./netcat_replacement.py -t 192.168.0.1 -p 135")

def main():
    global listen
    global port
    global execute
    global command
    global upload_destination
    global target

    if not len(sys.argv[1:]):
        usage()

    #read the command line options
    try:
        opts, args = getopt.getopt(sys.argv[1:], "hle:t:p:cu:",
        ["help","listen","execute", "target","port","command","upload"])
    except getopt.GetoptError as err:
        print(str(err).upper())
        usage()
    for o,a in opts:
        if o in ("-h", "--help"):
            usage()
        elif o in ("-l", "--listen"):
            listen=True
        elif o in ("-e", "--execute"):
            execute=a
        elif o in ("-c", "--commandshell"):
            command=True
        elif o in ("-u", "--upload"):
            upload_destination=a
        elif o in ("-t", "--target"):
            target=a
        elif o in ("-p", "--port"):
            port=int(a)
        else:
            assert False,"unhandled option"

main()
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please show the full stacktrace and mark the line at whick point the error occurs.

Comment: And there's your answer. It entered the exception and so never defined `ops` which was in the try block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What happens is, you try to define `ops` in the `try` block, but an exception occurs and you jump to the `except` block, so it isn't ever defined. After this, you try to access it in the succeeding lines in the loop, but since it is undefined at that point, you get the `UnboundLocalError`.

So, you catch an exception, notify the user an exception occurred, and then actually forget to terminate your program.

What you'd want to do is something along the lines of:

```
except getopt.GetoptError as err:
    print(str(err).upper())
    usage()

    return # <------ the return here
```

You'll use the return to break out of `main` without executing any of the code following it, because that's precisely what you *don't* what in the event of an exception.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. This was the issue. Once I added the return line, the problem was solved. Appreciate your help

Comment: @IpSp00f3r Glad to help!